# How can I wiew the source code for flutter commands (CLI)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'd like to view the source code for flutter commands like flutter run -d chrome and flutter build web. I'd like to know what's happening behind the scenes. Where are those files located?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1/packages/flutter_tools/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for the flutter tool eg CLI-tool is provided with flutter and located in [`<flutter install path>/packages/flutter_tools`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools).

For the run command, look at [`lib/src/commands/run.dart`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/run.dart).